# How can I access the objects created by DirectionsRenderer in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

Is there an easy way to get access to the objects/properties of the markers and infowindows created by the DirectionsRenderer?  (i.e. the "A" and "B" endpoints of the route)

I'm looking to replace the "A" & "B" markers' infowindows with one that I've created (containing dynamic content) from another "non-route" marker.

I've tried to copy the content from the previous infowindow into the new "route one" like this below, but it doesn't render properly (too many ancestor div & styling constraints).

```
//infowin is a reference to the infowindow attached to the marker    
result.routes[0].legs[0].end_address = MarkersArray[i].infowin.getContent();
```

Thanks,
E

Comment: I assumed that as "directionsDisplay.setMap(null);" is used to clear the "A" & "B" markers, that some method or syntax would be able to access the "A" & "B" markers via the directionsDisplay object...

However, further investigation seems to suggest that if someone wants to access/manage directions-markers, that they need to be manually created, plotted and tracked. 

There is a good example here, under "Inspecting DirectionsResults"
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DirectionsResults

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve the same problem. I dont't found any method to get the standart start or end icon.

You can disable the icons for the route and set a coustom [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#SimpleIcons).

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  var image = 'beachflag.png';
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });
```